# AngularJS - Acess login page outside onepage application

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Its possible to access a login page, outside the structure of single page application? I have this code:

```
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController'
});
```

Dashboard is inside the structure of single page application, using the template of my index.html, but my login page should be a external page, that not use the index.html as a template...

is that possible using ngRoute?

Comment: it's better if you create external app for your login page, for your question no you can't make it run outside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Maher. If I do this, I'll have to put the login app to run in one especific port and the rest of the application in other port =/

Comment: i put the main answer because i rejected for answering you by comment

Comment: The other `port` isn't necessary, make both of them in one `port`, it's much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The login page should be external as you said, so we have to put it outside of main app, for that we just have:

1. login app
2. main app

**benefits of make it external app are:**

1. the login not related to your main app it's just for authentication
2. the login app not include a lot of states **max 2 state** it's just login form or forget password
3. once users use `login app` to sign into your `main app` not more

Comment: that mean you for one time use the `login app` you just insert the `username` and `password` and then you will go to the `main app`

Comment: so, you suggest creating 2 distinct modules in my application? The login page should use another template, not the same index.html that the main application use... can u give a example?

Comment: or you think that is better create two diferent's applications?

Comment: exactly it's better, you will figure out when you make it possible yourself